# "An unexplained error ocurred" when connecting on ISO cd

Tags: vcenter

While using vSphere vCenter client, I try to connect to a local or network ISO cd and I get "an unexplained error ocurred".

If I connect directly to the ESXi host I can use the ISO image.
  So the problem is related on vCenter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

make sure the host has a DNS defined
I set the DNS entry in the network device configuration to 127.0.0.1 and it helped